# ansible playbook is failing

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

part of playbook is given below:This is the ansible playbook(main.yml)

```
         - name: setting Info data
           set_fact:
             application_data:
                log_file_name: "{{ log_file_name }}"
                log_file_dir: "{{ log_file_dir }}"

         - name: call application
           custom_application:
               verb: 'call'
               body: "{{ application_data }}"
           register: activate_output
```

custom_application.py:

this is the custom ansible application getting called from main.yml file.

```
 ###couple of imports


        def main():
            fields = {
                "verb": {"required": True, "type": "str"},
                "body": {"required": True, "type": "str"},

            }
            module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=fields)
            verb = module.params['verb']
            body = yaml.load(module.params['body'])
            application = application()   
            response = application.call(body)
            module.exit_json(changed=True, meta=response)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

Application.py:
python class that does couple of application related things.

```
def call(body):
   application = {}
   application["is_activated"]=True
   return application
```

above the main.yaml and custom ansible module and application class

```
        fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
            "changed": false,
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "",
            "module_stdout": "\"changed\": true, \"meta\": {\"is_activated\": true}}\n",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
            "rc": 0
        }
```

Module_stdout is as below:

module stdout i truncated the exact module_stdout is given below:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "{
           \"invocation\": {
               \"module_args\": {
                     \"body\": \"{
                       'application_id': '3f17f2a3-0510-457d-a164-72f3a71c6455', 
                       'file_path': '/tmp/vishnu.json', 
                       'log_file_name': '42ae1299-9cbf-49d3-82da-d2d1eb108eef-2017-09-09-11:26:03.log', 
                       'log_file_dir': '/home/oracle/logs/oracle/'
                      }\",
                      \"verb\": \"activate\"
                  }
              }, 
          \"changed\": false, 
          \"meta\": {
             \"is_activated\": true}
     }\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
}
```

and i think its a valid json object.

a particular ansible step is failing as shown above with no stderr. and i am also getting warning as above.. let me know where i went wrong

Note: i am sending json data as the output of custom ansible module as well

Comment: anyone if knows the solution let me know

Comment: show you playbook tasks, really hard to guess like this

Comment: added basic template of the code let me know where the prob exists @ArbabNazar

Comment: anyone? knows please give a shot

Comment: If you save the module stdout to a text file and feed it through one of the on-line JSON parser/linter tools (use Google and search for "json validator"), does the JSON pass the tests?

Comment: If you simplify the JSON output your module is producing, does the error go away?

Comment: @dan_linder if i post module_stdout into jsonlint.com its shows its a valid json

Answer (score 0):

From `module_stdout` you can see that the opening `{` is missing, giving you invalid JSON object, thus module is failing.

Check that your application doesn't mess with standard output.

Comment: modified the post with what i got as module_stdout ..and i hope that the json is valid one.

Comment: any solution you can suggest me with ? @Konstantin Suvorov

Comment: in your example `body` is multiline string... and as far as I know, JSON doesn't support multiline strings.